# Recomentations for validating JSON schema in Sharepoint Lists

Tags: json, schema, sharepoint-online

I'm very new to using JSON schemas in Microsoft (Sharepoint) Lists & would like a few pointers. I've created a column in Lists & have formatted it using JSON schema. It works, but when I save it an error flashes up on the bottom of the screen.
[image: Image showing error]

My question is how am I meant to validate the code. The error message is just splashed messily at the bottom of the screen?? What am I missing? How is one meant to debug that?.

Like I said above, the code works so that's not the issue, but it annoys me that I cannot easily validate my code to see what's causing the error. Can someone recommend a tool I can use to test the JSON schema code out when I write it in a SharePoint list.

I'm not including the code here, as my request is about recommendations for tools to help me validate JSON schema code, rather than fix a specific error.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with your JSON code. This issue is with REST API call made behind the scene to save the JSON formatting in column settings.

You can try adding JSON formatting in another list in same site or list in other site to narrow down your issue. It can be related to your column or list or site.

Meanwhile try using this steps to add JSON formatting to column:

1. From SharePoint list, click on Setting (gear) icon and select "List settings"
2. On list settings page, scroll down to the "Columns" section and click on column name where you want to apply JSON formatting
3. On column settings page, scroll down to "Column Formatting" section, paste your JSON in textbox below it and click "OK" to save column settings:

[image]

**Documentation**: [SharePoint column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Related article to get count of comments in list using JSON formatting: [Working with SharePoint Online/Microsoft List Comments using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/10/working-with-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list-comments-using-json-formatting/)